# how to hide user id and other parameters in a jsp url?

Tags: javascript, jsp, url, web, uri

I have a URL using which users access my jsp web application

http:/testerpages.com/testpage/menu1?userId=27

how can i hide userID=27 from users and show the url something like

http://testerpages.com/testpage/menu1

is there any method by which we can hide parameters from users or we can just ignore the ids but there is a threat for security if we show id parameters in a url directly to front end users

i m calling this page using

```
<a href="#" onclick="goToURL('${param.userId}','${contextPath}/menu1?userId=')">Menu1</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HEX(AES_ENCRYPT(userid,'"key"'))
```

use it in your sql or mysql query that will aes encrypt your userid i made use of it in mysql 
that should solve your problem

Comment: do you mean that i should use it in my select query and bring encrypted userid from database

Comment: yes exactly that should encrypt userid and while any other operation you just have to decrypt it with the same key used for encryption decryption syntax is HEX(AES_DECRYPT(userid,'"key"'))

Answer (score 0):

You could transfer this parameters als GET whicht don't show in the url, but are also very easy to read and modify. Instead I would use some kind of encrytion and validation code for session ids. This would prevent users and attackers from accesing other users sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the user ID in the session after the user logged in. When a user accesses the menu page, you can still get the ID from the session, and you will not need to put it into the URL.

Comment: thanks!!! for user id i can definetly use sessions any ideas for user data id's like list records for ex..users > data parent level record ids >> and data child level record ids ...:)

Comment: @tina sorry I do not understand your comment is this an other question?